# Design Choice - 2D house plan

Tags: c#, data-structures, 2d

I'm trying to figure out the best way to structure my program.

I plan to represent a 2D house plan with **walls, doors, windows and columns**. Walls are of fixed size and are added one by one. Columns can only be placed at the sides of a wall. Doors/windows go in the same spots as columns.

Also, in the future I plan to store the plans on a database. I don't mind doing some kind of data conversion to save/load the plans as long as it facilitates the manipulation of the plans within the program.

Example:
[image: Example plan]

**My ideas so far:**

- Using two Matrices, one to represent the walls and another to represent the columns/window/doors. **Cons:** The wall matrix would be odd, you can fit more vertical walls than horizontal walls in a single "row" of the plan
- Using objects that store references to their adjacent objects. **Cons:** very counter intuitive and maybe it makes it hard to print the plan on the screen

I'm pretty sure this is a very common scenario out there and hopefully I can get pointed on the right direction on what kind of data structure I can use to represent this internally.

Comment: You should search for open source software of the sort and get some inspiration from it.

Comment: I think this is off topic here, but I'll chime in anyway... You should not think about how to structure your data by how it is displayed. Think of how it will be arranged in memory, on disk, and modeled against reality. The display portion will follow afterwards.

Comment: @RonBeyer Well I'm think about it from many perspectives.. But most importantly about how it will be arranged in memory in a way that it provides easy and intuitive manipulation

Comment: @Aybe It's a good idea, but I doubt there's anything that relates to the simplicity of my scenario. Any plan drawing software out there will most likely not have fixed size walls, etc

Comment: This is not a bad question, and I would say it can be interesting to answer it, but unfortunately it's not a good fit to stackoverflow. You should probably post in on [SoftwareEngineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com). I'm voting to close.

Comment: @Chapi True, when I look at your picture it reminds of a 2D game level editor, with tiles, cells and snapping into a grid (maybe that'll give you an idea or two).

Comment: Also: Do get a) the constraints and b) the user interactions clear. a) What sizes are allowed, 4 doors? 1 window? Every wall ends in  a columnn?

Answer (score 0):

Using objects that store references to their adjacent objects is likely the better choice. Here's a few benefits:

- Smaller amounts of data to save/load; most of your matrices will be empty space, and just taking the actual objects out to be saved instead of saving the whole matrix will be smaller (in theory; if your saved objects are bulky, this benefit might not be realized)
- It's flexible; it's easier to add a new type of object or change how these objects fit together compared to a rigid matrix structure. This will make your code easier to maintain and expand, which is a long-term benefit. For instance, if you wanted to add walls of different lengths, this is much easier to achieve in an objects-based system than having to completely change your matrix design.
- You avoid the canvas size issue; If the user wants to expand their design, in a matrix solution you have to increase the size of the matrices which can be costly (esp. w/ regard to point 1) and annoying. With an objects system, you can define their position relative to some origin and decide the canvas size later (e.g. if we iterate over each object and find the min/max x and y over the whole set, the canvas size is the difference between those min/max values).

A simple way for implementing this is as follows:

- Every object has an x,y position
- To draw the canvas, first loop over every object and find the smallest x,y values and the largest x,y values
- e.g. if we have 3 objects with the following coordinates <3,4> <0,8> <-4,0> then our min x = -4, min y = 0, max x = 3, max y = 8, so our canvas is a rectangle from <-4,0> to <3,8>
- Shift the whole rectangle into the positive; in the example above, for instance, we'd add <4,0> to every object's position.
- Create a canvas with the x-length and y-height of the box you found (in the example, it'd be 7-wide and 8-tall, times some pixel-scale e.g. 10px/unit)
- Loop over every object and draw it at its shifted position (e.g. we'd draw the object with position <3,4> at <7,4>)

Comment: Could you provide a example picture of a plan with a couple walls/columns and their respective coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a multi-dimensional index, such as quadtree or R*Tree. Advantages:

- You are really free with your coordinates, elements don't have to 'lock' onto a given grid and you can turn objects (diagonal table, wall, ...)
- Checking collisions is relatively easy, just perform a range query (with a small margin) over an object (or over one of it's corners) and it will return all neighbors

Comment: I agree that structure is very flexible and can provide many advantages for more complex systems. But my problem is very simple (no rotations, locked to grid, fixed sizes), and I want to take advantage of its simplicity, using something like what you suggested is overkill